# How do I get typing working in python mixins?

Tags: python, django, mypy, python-typing

- I have a mixin that will always be used with a specific type of class i.e. a subclass of `widgets.Input`
- I want to override a few methods using the mixin, and I'm referencing attributes that exist on `widgets.Input` in my custom methods

How do I tell the python type system that this mixin extends the `widgets.Input` interface without inheriting from `widgets.Input`?

**Bonus:** Can I tell the type system that this mixin can only be used with subclasses of `widgets.Input`?

```py
from django.forms import widgets


class MaskedWidgetMixin:
    def format_value(self, value):
        return ""

    def get_context(self, name, value, attrs):
        context = super().get_context(name, value, attrs)  # <--- super().get_context does not exist
        context["widget"]["attrs"] = self.build_attrs(self.attrs, attrs, value)  # <--- self.attrs does not exist
        return context

    def build_attrs(self, base_attrs, extra_attrs=None, value: str = ""):
        attrs = super().build_attrs(base_attrs, extra_attrs)  # <--- super().build_attrs does not exist
        if value:
            attrs.update({"placeholder": "* ENCRYPTED *", "required": False})
        return attrs


class EncryptedTextInputWidget(MaskedWidgetMixin, widgets.TextInput):
    pass


class EncryptedTextareaWidget(MaskedWidgetMixin, widgets.Textarea):
    pass
```

### Update

As suggested in the comments, I tried to define a `Protocol`.
However this is not the exact purpose of a `Protocol`.
Rather a `Protocol` defines an interface to be implemented by the class extending it.

The following code produces this type error ...

```
Class derives from one or more protocol classes but does not implement all required members
  Member "attrs" is declared in protocol class "InputProtocol"
```

```py
class InputProtocol(Protocol):
    attrs: dict[str, Any]

    def get_context(self, name, value, attrs) -> dict[str, dict[str, Any]]:
        ...

    def build_attrs(self, base_attrs, extra_attrs=None) -> dict[str, Any]:
        ...


class MaskedWidgetMixin(InputProtocol):
    ...
```

Comment: Have you looked at `typing.Protocol`?  Seems like you could define a protocol that matches the `widgets.Input` interface and then declare that your mixin implements all of those methods.

Comment: Thanks @Samwise, could you show me an example?

Comment: Check out the mypy doc on protocols: https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/protocols.html

Comment: I think it would be optimal if I could derive a `Protocol` from `widgets.Input`, making it the single source of truth, and not have to define each method/attribute that I use, explicitly, on a custom, defined `Protocol`

Comment: Why did you declare `attrs` as a member of the protocol if it's not something that needs to be provided by the mixin?  Having to do a type: ignore defeats the purpose.

Comment: If I don't declare it, I will get a type error when referencing it in `get_context`. I think it is possible that you might not have understood the question.
I'm not defining a class that implements an interface, I'm declaring a class that expects that the class inheriting from it also inherits from a class that implements an interface.

Comment: Found a dupe with some good examples!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So far the best I've come up with is defining the `Protocol`, defining a class that pretends to implement it (ignoring the type error), and then inherit from the "fake"

**There must be a better way**

```py
from typing import Any, Protocol

from django.forms import widgets


class WidgetInputProtocol(Protocol):
    attrs: dict[str, Any]

    def get_context(self, name, value, attrs) -> dict[str, dict[str, Any]]:
        ...

    def build_attrs(self, base_attrs, extra_attrs=None) -> dict[str, Any]:
        ...


class WidgetInputMixin(WidgetInputProtocol):  # type: ignore
    pass


class MaskedWidgetMixin(WidgetInputMixin):
    def format_value(self, value):
        return ""

    def get_context(self, name, value, attrs):
        context = super().get_context(name, value, attrs)
        context["widget"]["attrs"] = self.build_attrs(self.attrs, attrs, value)
        return context

    def build_attrs(self, base_attrs, extra_attrs=None, value: str = ""):
        attrs = super().build_attrs(base_attrs, extra_attrs)
        if value:
            attrs.update({"placeholder": "* ENCRYPTED *", "required": False})
        return attrs


class EncryptedTextInputWidget(MaskedWidgetMixin, widgets.TextInput):
    pass


class EncryptedTextareaWidget(MaskedWidgetMixin, widgets.Textarea):
    pass
```